# Custom spacing in word 2013 list style

Tags: microsoft-word, styles

I'm trying to change the line spacing in a list style in Word 2013. Specifically, I'd like the line spacing to be 1.0 for all lines that are either the same list level as the line above or a sub-bullet of the previous line.

For all lines that are at a higher level than the previous line, I would like the line spacing to be 1.5.

Is this possible? If so, how?

here's an example:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1yy0.png]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by modifying a style
Ribbon > **Home** tab > **Styles** group > right click on a style and select "**Modify...**"
make further adjustment by clicking on Format > Paragraph > Indents and Spacing > Spacing

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Using this method I can change the spacing of all lines to one uniform width, but can I make different lines automatically have different spacing depending on their indent level relative to the line above?

Comment: I think its possible (much easier in powerpoint though). you can also try to create the list the way you want it first, then select the list, go to Ribbon > Home tab > Styles group > right click on a style and select "Update..". try using this updated style to a new list to see if it works.

Comment: xypha - it may be possible to do it by updating a style, but I haven't figure out how. I've tried and it never seems to work.